# переход с кнопки которая расположенная на yandex картах на карту google инициализируя текущее положение карты на yandex

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть функция `yandexmapconroller` которая инициализирует текущий центр карты, при смещении карты необходимо по кнопке открывать текущее положение карты.

Код js:

```js
this.txc = function() {
  var a = 'HTTPS://www.google.com/maps/@';
  window.open(a);
};
var button = new ymaps.control.Button({
  data: {
    content: 'Открыть в Google картах',
  },
  options: {
    maxWidth: 200
  }
});
button.events.add('press', this.txc);
this.map.controls.add(button, {
  float: 'none',
  position: {
    bottom: '45px',
    left: '9px'
  }
});
```

Если сюда `var a = 'HTTPS://www.google.com/maps/@';` я пробую добавить `this.map.getCenter()`, ссылка не открывается , если задаю глобальную переменную `var b = this.map.getCenter()`, всё рано пишет центр инициализированный центр изначальной карты , необходимо задать новый центр при переходе по кнопке, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку выдавалась на Гугл картах текущее положении карты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавил конструкцию

```
this.map.events.add('dblclick',function (e) {
var x =  e.originalEvent.map.getCenter();
var a = 'HTTPS://www.google.com/maps/@' + x + ',16z';
window.open(a);
```

переход происходит по нажатию два раза на область карты , но с нужным центром, теперь мучаюсь как эту функцию повесить на кнопку.
Всем спасибо , решение объявить объект this во внешней области видимости как var b = this , и использовать внутри функции на реакцию нажатия кнопки.